# In Illustrator CC, how can I export an SVG path laid down with the brush tool as that path

Tags: svg, path, fill, adobe-illustrator, stroke

In Illustrator CC, how can I export an SVG path laid down with the brush tool as that path with a stroke, instead of it automatically replacing it with a fill?

For whatever reason, when I export a path that was drawn with the brush tool (no fill and some colored stroke), the resulting SVG has changed the path to an outline of the path, and then it changed my stroke property to a fill.

This doesn't happen when I export a path that was created with the pen tool.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I am trying to export a path with variable width that was created using a pressure-sensitive wacom tablet. I think what I am trying to do isn't really possible with the current SVG spec. Right?

Answer (score 0):

There's no variable width paths in SVG 1.1 although I believe tapered stroke has been mooted for SVG 2.0.

Also ensure 'Align Stroke' is set to 'Center' in the 'Stroke' panel otherwise it will be converted to a fill.

Comment: Just realized my question wasn't specific enough. I am trying to export a path with variable width that was created using a pressure-sensitive wacom tablet. I think what I am trying to do isn't really possible with the current SVG spec. Right?

Comment: Chris can you post that comment as an answer so I can credit you? That is the answer to the question I meant to ask, and I have edited the question to be more clear.